# Why does the Hebrew word for father have א on the end of אבא?

Tags: hebrew

I am currently learning Hebrew and I'm confused over the word father (Aba).

Why does the Hebrew word for father have א on the end of אבא if you can use Niqqud?

Also, are you supposed to spell father as אַבָּא OR אַבַא?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MY! The word is most probably of Aramaic origin. Although I have to say, your question might be off topic on this site.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Can I also recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Finally note that Hebrew questions are out of scope for the site and your question might be closed. But I hope that doesn't deter you from staying and learning with us.

Answer (score 2):

אבא is an Aramaic for האב. In general, the definitive article ה in Hebrew becomes the final א in Aramaic.

Compare אמא - האם, סבא - הסב, רבא - הרב and more.

The right Nikkud is a Komotz: אַבָּא שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why there is a need for this letter though.

Comment: @mike1024 He’s saying that the word isn’t originally a Hebrew word, but rather an Aramaic one, where the grammar rules are different.